# Did the Hound know his role?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

Why did the Hound comply with Beric and decide to help Arya in *Game of Thrones* S08E03, when Beric pointed at Arya as she was fighting a lot of the dead?

Did the Hound know his role? Did the Lord of Light tell him something about this situation? Did he feel bad for Arya and he decided to help her? Is he sticking to that oath of protecting her?

He didn't want anything to do with the fight, that moment changed his mind and decided to fight for Arya. Is this part explained in the previous seasons about what his role is?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLiLtjrfVPM  Possible answer at 10:24 in the attached video.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Hound and Arya have a long history together. The Hound cares for Arya whether he would ever admit it or not. Beric pointing out Arya being in trouble just caused the Hound to realize he could help her and save her after she has helped and saved him before, including earlier in the fight.

The bigger question is possibly did the Lord of Light direct Beric to point to Arya in order to get the Hound to go help her. At least according to Melisandre Beric was supposed to get Arya to Melisandre and Arya was supposed to be the one to take out the Night King. So it is entirely possible the Lord of Light directed Beric to use Arya as a motivator for the Hound to get his act together and help him rescue and get Arya to her destination.

Comment: How much time did Beric and the Hound spend together after Septon Ray and the villagers were killed by the rogue Brothers Without Banners? I don't think it would take divine inspiration for Beric to know and understand that the Hound feels an affection and protective instinct towards Arya that he doesn't feel for anyone else.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet That's fair enough. Just throwing that out there as a possibility. You're probably right though.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLiLtjrfVPM Similar Answer found, at 10:24 in this video.

Comment: Note that the Hound's affection for Arya becomes more apparent during the meeting in the dragon arena, where he talks to Brienne, asks about Arya, and then [even cracks a smile](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PUv_-w7VFWc/maxresdefault.jpg) when he hears she is back home and doing well. Comparing that picture to his general demeanor, it is clear that he has grown to like Arya.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that Beric is pointing out Lyanna Mormont at that moment, and not Arya.

That takes his oath out of consideration, as well as any question of him having insight into the role he will play in getting Arya to her "destiny".  It points to it being more of a "shaming moment" for him.  Lyanna is only a child, and charges an undead giant single-handedly.

Comment: If you're pointing a mistake in the question, I think this should rather has been left as a comment, not an answer, as it doesn't explain whether or not the Hound knew his role. Or if does and I'm missing something, please edit your post to explain how. :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mc9cjvkFrFs  Pause the video at 0:22. Is that Arya or Lyanna? I don't know the screen is so dark!

Comment: It is Arya Beric is pointing to not Lyanna. The Hound doesn't really care about or know Lyanna.

Comment: Confirmed that it was Arya and not Lyanna Mormont.